# Xcode / GitHub - Committing Interface Setting Files

Tags: xcode, git, github

What do you normally do when Xcode tries to commit user setting files to git like this ones:

> xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/xcschemes
>
> xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad
>
> UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

If I push the files to the GitHub server, aren't they going to end up on another team members computer ?

What would be the best practice? Is there a way to omit commitment on this types of files, or omit the push to the remote server ?

What do you normally do?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `.gitignore` file - either at the repo level or the machine level - to tell git to ignore files, folders, etc... In this specific case, you would add `xcuserdata/` to the `.gitignore` and git will start ignoring those files. Note that if you've already committed anything within the `xcuserdata/` folder at least once, git will continue to track the file(s) even after you update the `.gitignore`.

Github maintains a repository of common `.gitignore` files for various languages, IDEs, etc..., which is available [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

There's also an Xcode-specific `.gitignore` example in that repo [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore).